# unicode is wrong when get file from server

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

I wanna download [this link](http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&hl=en&sl=auto&tl=fa&multires=1&prev=btn&ssel=0&tsel=3&uptl=fa&alttl=en&sc=1&text=hello) from google which mage txt file by php.

when I do it by browser,the unicode is correct and all things are right,but when I do it by `curl` or `file_get_content` it contain bad alphabets.
what is difference and how should I solve it?

downloaded by brower

```
[[["سلام","hello","",""]],[["interjection",["سلام","هالو","الو"],[["سلام",["hello","hi","aloha","all hail"]],["هالو",["hallo","hello","halloo"]],["الو",["hello"]]]]],"en",,[["سلام",[5],0,0,1000,0,1,0]],[["hello",4,,,""],["hello",5,[["سلام",1000,0,0],["خوش",0,0,0],["میهمان گرامی",0,0,0],["خوش آمدید",0,0,0],["درود کاربر",0,0,0]],[[0,5]],"hello"]],,,[["en"]],65]
```

download by following php script:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
$t = file_get_contents("http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&hl=en&sl=auto&tl=fa&multires=1&prev=btn&ssel=0&tsel=3&uptl=fa&alttl=en&sc=1&text=hello");
$f = fopen("t.txt", "w+");
fwrite($f, $t);
fclose($f);
?>
</body></html>
```

```
[[["ÓáÇã","hello","",""]],[["interjection",["ÓáÇã","åÇáæ","Çáæ"],[["ÓáÇã",["hello","hi","aloha","all hail"]],["åÇáæ",["hallo","hello","halloo"]],["Çáæ",["hello"]]]]],"en",,[["ÓáÇã",[5],0,0,1000,0,1,0]],[["hello",4,,,""],["hello",5,[["ÓáÇã",1000,0,0],["ÎæÔ",0,0,0],["ã\u06CCåãÇä ÑÇã\u06CC",0,0,0],["ÎæÔ ÂãÏ\u06CCÏ",0,0,0],["ÏÑæÏ ÇÑÈÑ",0,0,0]],[[0,5]],"hello"]],,,[["en"]],4]
```

---

Header:

```
Header are:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Fri, 25 May 2012 22:29:12 GMT
Expires: Fri, 25 May 2012 22:29:12 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=600
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: fa
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=b6c08a0545f50594:TM=1337984952:LM=1337984952:S=Sf1xcow2qPZrFeu0; expires=Sun, 25-May-2014 22:29:12 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Disposition: attachment
Server: HTTP server (unknown)
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Comment: When doing the `curl` request, did you pass any `Accept:` and `Accept-Charset:` headers?

Comment: I tried both of them(send utf8 or blank),but the problem exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parameters `ie=UTF-8` and `oe=UTF-8` to query string of the url:

```
$t = file_get_contents("http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&client=t&hl=en&sl=auto&tl=fa&multires=1&prev=btn&ssel=0&tsel=3&uptl=fa&alttl=en&sc=1&text=hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me once, as I was about to throw lots of code to the garbage! Maybe it will help you too

```
iconv( 'CP1252', 'UTF-8', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo`ing what you get from `file_get_contents` into the PHP output should work fine, as you are going from a UTF-8 JSON response to a UTF-8 HTML response. Works for me off the given URL.

When you store to a file, you then have to worry about what encoding the tools you are using to read the file are working in. Just `fwrite`ing is fine as long as the text editor you view it in knows the output is UTF-8. On Windows, Notepad may instead try to read it in the locale-dependent default ('ANSI') codepage, which won't be UTF-8. On a Western European install it'd be code page 1252 and you'd get output like `Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù…` for `سلام`.

(One way around that is to put a UTF-8 fake-BOM at the front of the file with `fwrite($f, "\xef\xbb\xbf");`. This is a bit dodgy because UTF-8 doesn't need a Byte Order Mark (its byte order is fixed) and it breaks UTF-8's ASCII-compatibility, but Windows tools like fake-BOMs. The other way around it is to get a better text editor that allows you to default to handling files as UTF-8.)

You've got something slightly different here, as `ÓáÇã` is what you get when you save `سلام` in the Windows default Arabic encoding (code page 1256) and then read it in the Windows default Western encoding (code page 1252). This implies there's some kind of extra store-and-load step involved in your testing, that's messing up the encoding.

If it's anything to do with Windows command line tools you might as well give up, because the Command Prompt and MSVCRT apps don't really play well with Unicode at all.